# Adding ImageView to the left of the radio group?

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, radio-group

I'm trying to add an ImageView to a RadioGroup.  Preferably as part of the RadioGroup but to the left of all of the RadioButtons that are inside the group.  I can make it appear on the bottom by simply adding it as the last item, but I would like to get it to appear to the left.

See my code and a picture below.

Code for getting it to appear on bottom:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) currentLayout.findViewWithTag("rg" + fld_id);

errorImage = new ErrorImageView(this);
errorImage.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.redxsmall);
errorImage.setScaleX(0.8f);
errorImage.setScaleY(0.8f);

rg.addView(errorImage);
```

Picture:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RadioGroup` inherits from `LinearLayout`. That means it only supports placing views below **or** right of each other.

If you want both you have to wrap your `RadioGroup` inside another `ViewGroup`, e.g. a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) currentLayout.findViewWithTag("rg" + fld_id);

errorImage = new ErrorImageView(this);
errorImage.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.redxsmall);
errorImage.setScaleX(0.8f);
errorImage.setScaleY(0.8f);

rg.addView(0,errorImage);
errorImage.setTranslationY(100);
LayoutParams  params = new Layoutparams(100,100);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
rg.getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(params)
```